# jQuery plugin .live() to .on()

Tags: jquery, plugins, live

How to change

```
$.fn.ajaxFormPostLink = function() {    
    this.live('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
```

...

to somenthig using `.on()` not `.live()`, i tried:

```
$.fn.ajaxFormPostLink = function() {    
    $("body").on('click', this, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
```

...

but id does not work, so how to change `live()` to `on()` in jQuery plugin.

Comment: You cannot easily do this. You don't know what `this` is, i.e. how it was created. Your `.live` version probably worked "coincidentally" because you always used it as `$('.foo').ajaxFormPostLink()`, but `$('.foo').children().ajaxFormPostLink()` would already have failed. The whole approach is very fragile.

Comment: The second parameter of the `on` method should be a string not an object.

Comment: `.on` doesn't accept `this` (jQuery object) as a valid args. The valid arg is a simple selector string.

Comment: Not sure I get it, why exactly would you need a delegated event handler on `this`. If the plugin is initialized on that element, it already exists ?

Comment: You should rethink the plugin. It doesn't make much sense to apply a plugin to elements that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 3):

Rebuild the plugin to be used this way:

```
$.ajaxFormPostLink(".someform",{... options ...});
```

for example:

```
$.ajaxFormPostLink = function(selector,options) {

    $(document).on("click",selector,function(){
        ...
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("body").on('click', this.selector, function() {
```

Assuming you are dealing with simple jQuery object.

Comment: wasn't `this.selector` removed since `.live` was removed?

Comment: Although this might work, according to the documentation , `.selector` was officially removed in 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/selector/. And it will have the same problem as `.live` had: It won't work with chained function calls.

Comment: This WILL not work on complex selector. The way selector is passed on how it is set in actual object is different.

Comment: @FelixKling I've checked with 1.9.1 - it is still there.

Comment: @freakish: I know, but officially it was removed... at least it's unclear what is happening to it now.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't know what that means. :D Is it supposed to be removed? Otherwise it's completely ok to use it.

Comment: The documentation claims: *"version removed: 1.9"*